# How to avoid image flickering in a listview

Tags: android, image, android-imageview, universal-image-loader

I have a listivew that display a bunch of images. am using **Universal Image Loader** to load this images from files to imageviews.

This images have different dimensions and i want all of them to have same width but different height in respect to each image aspect ratio.

To achieve this, i have tried setting the following to my imageview

```
<ImageView
   android:layout_width = "400dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:scaleType="centerCrop"
   android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

The issue with this method is that **there is a lot of flickering when one scrolls the listview since imageview height is not known in advance and images have to be scaled first using my width to calculate each image height in respect to it's aspect ratio**.

How can i calculate each image height in advance instead of letting imageview handle it?

if i have an image which is 400 X 700, and i want the imageview to be 300px wide, how can i calculate imageview's height using my image dimension and maintain image aspect ratio? this can help avoid flickering wnen one scroll the listview.

Comment: why don't you set a fixed height too ? and use animations like a quite fade in to make it more smoth ? The ration is kept by the scaleType parameter :)

Comment: @An-droid       i don't want to set a fixed height. am trying to achieve what imageview does in the background. if you set a fixed width and set height to **wrap content**, it will scale the image and calculate height. but i want to calculate height in advance so that the user won't see that ugly resizing of imageview when he/she scroll through the images

Comment: In well known applications like Spotify, most of the imageViews are just set with fixed sizes or matchparent and scaleType set to centerCrop. What does it do ? the image will fill all the space you give to it and will be proportionally resized in accordance to her height. It's good because you don't know which devices users will use your application on, with which density... using fixed width is, well dirty and dangerous I think

Comment: @An-droid      have you ever used whatsapp or any chat app where you can send images?. images are resized very well and even when you send like 20 images, you won't see imageview's resizing themselves. everything is smooth. am trying to implement something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of research, i was able to know the method that i can use to calculate new imageview height while maintaining image aspect ratio.

```
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

//Returns null, sizes are in the options variable
BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/image.png", options);
int width = options.outWidth;
int height = options.outHeight;

//calculating image aspect ratio
float ratio =(float) height/(float) width;

//calculating my image height since i want it to be 360px wide
int newHeight = Math.round(ratio*360);

//setting the new dimentions
 imageview.getLayoutParams().width = 360;
 imageview.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;

 //i'm using universal image loader to display image
 imaheview.post(new Runnable(){
  ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageuri,imageview,displayoptions);
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this flicker is that, in listview list items are reused. When re-used, the imageviews in the list item retains the old image reference which is displayed first. Later on once new image is downloaded, it starts to show. this causes the flickering behavior. 
To avoid this flickering issue, always clear the old image reference from the imageview when it is getting reused.

In your case, add **holder.image.setImageBitmap(null);** after  **holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();**

So, your getView() method will look like:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ...

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(viewResourceId, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(null)
    }

    ...

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: this was also one of the issue **but what i mean** is that when i scroll down, imageview appears with width of 400px and height of 0. and then after calculating the height, **it suddenly appears.** i want to calculate the height in advance and set it to image view to avoid **Resizement og imageview**

Comment: did you understand my concern?

Comment: `holder.setImageBitmap(null)` is the same as using `.resetViewBeforeLoading(true)` in the universal image loader DisplayImageOptions()

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

//Returns null, sizes are in the options variable
BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/image.png", options);
int width = options.outWidth;
int height = options.outHeight;
//If you want, the MIME type will also be decoded (if possible)
String type = options.outMimeType;
```

Answer (score 0):

How I solved it was by creating a `Bitmap[]` array variable to store images, then in adapter's `getView()`, I used position to check if image in `Bitmap[]` array is `null` or has value. If it is has value, then I use the value instead of calling the `new DownloadImageTask()` construct again.

For example:

**YourCustomArrayAdapter.java**

```
public class MyCustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
   private static Bitmap[] myListViewImageViewsArray = new Bitmap[listViewItemsArray.length];
   private String[] myListViewImageURLsArray = new String[listViewItemsArray.length]{
      "image_url_1",
      "image_url_2",
      ...
      ...
   };


   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){
       CustomViewHolder vHolder;
        if(view == null){
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.movies_coming_soon_content_template, null, true);
            vHolder = new CustomViewHolder();
            vHolder.imageView = (AppCompatImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_cutom_image);
            vHolder.imageUrl = "";
            view.setTag(vHolder);
        }
        else{
            vHolder = (CustomViewHolder)view.getTag();
            // -- Set imageview src to null or some predefined placeholder (this is not really necessary but it might help just to flush any conflicting data hanging around)
            vHolder.imageView.setImageResource(null);
        }

       // ... 


       // -- THIS IS THE MAIN PART THAT STOPPED THE FLICKERING FOR ME
       if(myListViewImageViewsArray[position] != null){
          vHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(myListViewImageViewsArray[position]);
       }else{
          new DownloadImageTask(position, vHolder.imageView).execute(vHolder.imageUrl);
       }
       // -- END OF THE FLICKERING CONTROL    
   }
}
```

Then, in your image downloader construct, after downloading the image, make an insertion into the `Bitmap[]` image array for that position. For example:

**YourImageDownloaderClass.java**

```
public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
   AppCompatImageView imageView;
   int position;

   public DownloadImageTask(int position, AppCompatImageView imageView){
       this.imageView = imageView;
       this.position = position;
   }

   @Override
   protected Bitmap doInBackground(String...urls) {

       String urlOfImage = urls[0];
       Bitmap logo = null;
       try{            
           logo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(urlOfImage).getContent());
       }catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();            
       }
       return logo;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result){
       if(result != null) {
          YourCustomArrayAdapter.myListViewImageViewsArray [position] = result;
          imageView.setImageBitmap(result);                    
       }else{
          YourCustomArrayAdapter.myListViewImageViewsArray [position] = null;
          imageView.setImageResource(null);                  
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @CodyGray. I'm still very new to posting answers. Hopefully I'll get better over time.

Comment: No worries! Your answer was already helpful. [Another user and I](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45533135/revisions) just cleaned up some formatting and English grammar. Thanks for caring about the site and trying to improve!

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is to use grid view to avoid flickering of images it will load at first time if it is same url , it will load from cache

```
 Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(item.getImageUrl())
            .into(holder.mIVGridPic);
```